# Bash Shell rename multiple file name

Tags: bash, macos, shell, mv

I need to rename files like

```
filename-367519.mp4 
otherfilename-367515.mp4
andotherfilename-377530.mp4
```

to

```
367519-filename.mp4
...
```

Comment: What did your googling turn up? What did you learn from all of the other questions about file renaming?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple script for you.

```
#!/bin/bash

full_filename=$(basename $1)
filename_noextension="${full_filename%%.*}"

filename=$(echo "$filename_noextension" | cut -d"-" -f1);
number=$(echo "$filename_noextension" | cut -d"-" -f2);
extension="${full_filename##*.}"

result="$number-$filename.$extension"

mv $1 $result
```

run it with:
`bash ./rename.sh filename-367519.mp4`

Note that command `cut` use sign `-` as delimiter, and later it is used in `result="$number-$filename.$extension"` as just a string.

Reference:
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal

Comment: I got to much space in all file name so i do a loop with a script to replace white space with '_'
FILES=*
for f in $FILES
do
 mv "$f" `echo $f | tr ' ' '_'`
 
done
than with same loop I use you code

Thank so much.

Comment: If that solved your problem, please mark the question as an answered. More points for me then, yay!